# Extract field form django model

Tags: python, django, models

I have defined the following model:

```
class User(models.Model):
    userid = models.CharField(max_length=26,unique=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=5)
```

Now I would like to extract the value of my status field for a specific userid that I have saved in my database. I am doing it currently in this way:

```
field = User.objects.filter(userid=id).values('status')
```

Which gives me a Query Set, e.g.:

```
<QuerySet [{'status': 'some status'}]>.
```

However, I am not looking for the Query Set but for the Field string. So I am currently doing a workaround to get the field value:

```
field1 = str(field)
field2 = field1.replace("<QuerySet [{'status': '","")
field3 = field3.replace("'}]>","")
```

Which returns me: "some status". That is obviously super messy. So what would be the correct way to get the field string "some status" for this example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I've understood your problem, you can simply do as follows:

```
# Get your user
user = User.objects.get(userid=id)

# save the status
status = user.status

# print it!
print status # 'some status'
```

Comment: The reason he is getting the said output in the first place is because it is returning an model object. To get the specific info, do as advised here by @floatingpurr

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly the answer I was looking for!